# Why does the UIButton never hide, and then come back unhidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So `self.pic` is the UIButton that I want to hide. But it never actually hides it for some reason.

Please Help

```
- (void)tick:(NSTimer*)time
{
    self.pic.hidden = YES;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    self.pic.hidden = NO;

    [self.pic setEnabled:NO];
    if (self.checkPic == YES)
    {
        self.lives--;
        self.livesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives : %d", self.lives];

    }
    [self.pic setImage:[self backgroundImageForGame] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self check];

    self.pic.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Never sleep on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate on what @rmaddy said in his comment, you shouldn't ever sleep the main (or UI) thread. When you do this, you're blocking the thread that is responsible for making the visual changes to the button, like whether or not it is hidden. The solution is to do the waiting asynchronously, and GCD has a built in function that makes this painless.

`dispatch_after()` allows you to create a block that will be executed after a specified delay, on a queue of your choosing. Since you want to update the UI, you'll want to come back to the main queue to make the changes to the on screen button. Here's an example:

```
self.pic.hidden = YES;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.pic.hidden = NO;
});
```